# Angular - Change a different value every time a function is executed

Tags: angular

Working in Angular. Marvel-Hero Component has the following code

```
export class MarvelHerosComponent implements OnInit {

  hero = ["IronMan","Hulk","Thor"]   


    ChangeHero() {
        this.hero[1] = "Black Panther"
    }

}
```

And in the html file of the component I've the following code with the event placed on the button

```
<p>Hero 1 is {{hero[0]}}</p>
<p>Hero 2 is {{hero[1]}}</p>
<p>Hero 3 is {{hero[2]}}</p>

<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="ChangeHero()">Change Hero</button>
```

**What I want to achieve is everytime the change hero button is clicked the values of array are changed one by one**

Example:
When I click the Change hero button 
1st time: IronMan changes to Black Panther 
2nd time: Hulk changes to Black Panther 
3rd time: Thor changes to Black Panther

Also, If I wasn't using an array for Hero and had hero1, hero2 as my variables would changing of the value be possible with every click?

I have tried using a for loop and inserting the value of the variable in

```
this.hero[x]
```

But that only further created a confusion. I am unable to create a logic for this.

Comment: you want to display three lines everytime or one line?

Comment: What have you tried? consider to keep track of the clicks through an internal variable and access positions of the array though it. I wont leave an answer, as I consider this question to be really basic and wont help any other users others than yourself.

Comment: You want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arv8ja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @PardeepJain One Line.

Comment: @PardeepJain Thank You this is exactly what I wanted.
Please post the code as answer so I can mark your answer as helpful (Accept).
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChangeHero() {
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter >= this.hero.length){
        this.counter = 0;
      } else {
        this.showHero = this.hero[this.counter]
      }

<p> {{showHero}} changes to Black Panthe</p>
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="ChangeHero()">Change Hero</button>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arv8ja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)